# DSS crypto algorithm confusion

Tags: cryptography

Here is the exercise:

Suppose that $(p,p_1,g_1,a)=(107, 53,4,13)$ is the public key for a digital signature and $(52,47),(29,7)$ are the signatures of the messages $m=15$ and $m'=12$, correspondingly. If $k,k'=2 k$ are the daily keys that have been used then find out the **private key :** $h$

What I did:

According to the statement we can make two congruences:

$47k\equiv15+52h\mod53$   (1)

$14k\equiv12+29h\mod53$   (2)

Multiplying the (1) by $14$, the (2) by $-47$ and sum together, I get $$52h\equiv17\mod53$$   or $$h\equiv36\mod53$$

But if $h=36$, then it should also be $$a\equiv4^h\mod107$$ or $$13\equiv4^{36}\mod107$$, which is wrong...

Is the exercise correct or am I making a mistake? Thanks.

Related DSS document

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Moo, I edited the question and added some related documents.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you use twice the same $k$ (which I assume you use for the random $r$ from your description) They will need to be different per signature.

Comment: Of course $h=7$ is easy to find by other means.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I am terrible sorry I made a typo, I edited my question concerning $k' =2k$.Thanks

Comment: I get a different but also wrong $h$ when I solve the equations.

Comment: What is your $h$, please? And also the solution of (1) and (2) is  $h=36, k=30$, which means that $k'=60>53$....But $k'$ should be less than $52$ according to the algorithm...@HennoBrandsma

Comment: If $k=30$ then $k’=7$ of course.